# Trying to add files to SMB Server on iOS, getting the error of "Attribute not found" (OMV)

Tags: samba, smb, nas, openmediavault

Just to begin, I am quite new to this, and not the very knowledgeable, so thank you for any help in advance, and please ask me for anything that I left off. Ok now to the problem.

I been trying to make a NAS for alternative video storage other than iCloud. In the begin I had a few hiccups but I got it working, it was working great on Windows and iOS until we tried to test 15ish videos at once on iOS(through the files app, the default one), it never upload any of the videos completely, and when we canceled it and tried to upload just one at a time, it said "Attribute not  found.

I also have tried 2 things already, setting `fruit:nfs_aces` to no, and putting this `vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr` down

Btw, this is a OpenMediaVault server, and I was using SMB in the files app. Windows still works perfectly fine, just iOS is being screwy.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, you have to add description to that file before sending it from iOS to NAS

Comment: Nice finding. That's definitely a bug on iOS. It works normally on macOS and as you pointed out - adding caption to the photo on iOS helps. Very inconvenient if you'd like to upload multiple files in one shot.